# How should mustard seeds be collected?

Tags: seeds, seed-saving, brassicas

This is probably a simple question but I just want to know any common advice for collecting seeds from mustard greens.

4-5 self-seeded mustards (Brassica juncea) popped up in the autumn and I just let them go to be green manure, but I've neglected to hoe them back into the soil so far. Now the seed pods are getting quite large and so I may as well collect those before turning the plants into green manure. Any advice on how I can collect as much mustard seed as possible from them?

1. Do I remove the stalks (that contain the pods) from the plant now (they're not yet brown)?
2. I assume I'm then supposed to hang up the stalks some place safe where they won't be disturbed until completely dried.
3. Do I need to put bags or containers under the stalks in case the seeds start dropping out by themselves?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have never collected mustard seed, but I can tell you my standard approach to seed collecting. Wait until that pods just start opening or are turning brown. Then cut the stalks off and dump them head first in a paper bag. *Label the bag.* Let the seed heads dry out in the bag for a few weeks. Collect the seed from the bags, and put them in a sealed dry container in the frig. *Label the container.*

Comment: Upvote for "Label the container".  So easy to do it later...